# ReferenceError: inject is not defined (not to do with file dependency with the script tags)

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I looked around and saw that angular-mocks.js should be included in the html page to resolve this. I added this, but protractor was still throwing me the error.

I'm relatively new to angular so if I would really appreciate any tips / suggestions to this problem.

Here are my files:

**index.html**

```
...
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="js/daily-summary.js"></script>
<script src="js/add-word.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="view1/view1.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="view2/view2.js"></script> -->
<script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
```

**scenarios.js**

```
'use strict';

/* https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/toc.md */

describe('my app', function() {
  describe('Add Word Controller', function() {
    var session;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, localStorageService) { // <-- line that throws error 
      //  set up
      module('myApp');

      //  fetch resources
      browser.get('partials/add-word.html');

      //  assign local storage service
      session = localStorageService;
    }));

    afterEach(inject(function(localStorageService) {
      //  clear entry after each operation
      localStorageService.set(Date.getDate(), '');
    }));

    it('should add a word to local storage when user enters a new word', function() {
      //  define the input elements
      var word = element(by.css('.add-word input:nth-child(1)'));
      var definition = element(by.css('.add-word input:nth-child(2)'));
      var sentence = element(by.css('.add-word textarea'));

      var addWord = element(by.css('.add-button'));

      //  emulate the type and click events
      var wordObject = {
        word: 'Animals',
        definition: 'A living organism that feeds on organic matter',
        sentence: 'There are a lot of animals in the jungle'
      }

      word.sendKeys(wordObject.word);
      definition.sendKeys(wordObject.definition);
      sentence.sendKeys(wordObject.sentence);

      addWord.click();

      //  expect there to be a word
      var fetchedWord = session.get(Date.getDate());
      expect(fetchedWord).toEqual(wordObject);

    });
  });  
});
```

**add-word.js**

```
...
.controller('AddWordCtrl', ['$scope', 'localStorageService', function($scope, localStorageService) {
    $scope.addWord = function() {
        //  get day of month
        var dateObject = new Date();
        var dayOfMonth = dateObject.getDate();

        //  grab word stored in (day, words) pair
        var currentWords = localStorageService.get(dayOfMonth) || [];

        //  JSON format object
        var wordObject = {
            word: $scope.newWord, 
            definition: $scope.newDefinition, 
            sentence: $scope.newSentence
        };

        //  add word to array
        currentWords.push(wordObject);

        //  update local storage (key, value) pair
        localStorageService.set(dayOfMonth, currentWords);

        //  update success message
        $scope.successMessage = "New word added";

        //  lock the two inputs, one textarea and one add button
        $scope.locked = true;
    };
}])
;
```